# Bootstrap 3 grid boxes should take free vertical space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Actually I am working with bootstrap 3.3.6 and want to achive following with the bootstrap grid system:

[image]

The boxes are all in the same `<div class="row">` tag and i want that the box 4 takes the available space on the left side below the box 1.

The jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/byrd9wx2/

I know how to do this with normal html + css but not with bootstrap.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use masonry for that https://jsfiddle.net/byrd9wx2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using Bootstrap grid system by reordering **Box2** & **Box3** and floating those to right.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

 .content-box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.mainbody{
  padding: 50px;
}

.box-spacing{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="mainbody">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box-spacing">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div style="background: yellow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box-spacing pull-right">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div style="background: yellow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box-spacing pull-right">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div style="background: yellow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box-spacing">
            <div class="content-box">
                <div style="background: yellow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: floating those to right by adding **pull-right** class

Comment: smooth, i like it

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to place both of **BOX1** and **BOX4** within first column.

```css
#box1 {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#box2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
#box3 {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#box4 {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
#box1,#box2,#box3,#box4 {
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div id="box1">BOX1</div>
      <div id="box4">BOX4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div id="box2">BOX2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div id="box3">BOX3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also thought about this but they need to be in separate containers.
Thanks anyway!